# WSO2 IS serverOrigin is not used from config

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, wso2-identity-server

I'm new to WSO2 IS.

- wso2 runs in docker: serverOrigin - https://localhost:9443
- Build an SPA (vuejs) . script below
- By login/signIn the serverOrigin is not being used. Instead I’m forwarded to https://api.asgardeo.io/t/%3Corg_name%3E/oauth2/authorize instead of https://localhost:9443/t/appname

**Why provided ServerOrigin in config Object is not used?**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { AsgardeoSPAClient, AuthSPAClientConfig } from "@asgardeo/auth-spa";
import { onMounted } from "vue";

const config: AuthSPAClientConfig = {
  signInRedirectURL: "http://localhost:8080",
  signOutRedirectURL: "http://localhost:8080",
  clientID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  serverOrigin: "https://localhost:9443/t/tenant",
};

const auth: AsgardeoSPAClient = AsgardeoSPAClient.getInstance()!;

onMounted(init);

async function init() {
  const spa = await auth.initialize(config);

  console.log(spa, auth);
}

async function login() {
  auth.signIn();
}

async function getToken() {
  const accessToken = await auth.getAccessToken();
  console.log(accessToken);
}
</script>
```

the url is called

```
https://api.asgardeo.io/t/<org_name>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
&
client_id=xxxxxx
&
scope=openid
&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
&
response_mode=query
&
code_challenge_method=S256
&
code_challenge=a8dUNbiWc19frjgg2IRHjPS_juzBvqcVjOCkk-XIpGE
```

I see that other config are published except **serverOrigin**, why?

Answer (score 1):

just downgraded from 0.2.19 to version @asgardeo/auth-spa:0.2.18 and now I’m forwarded to serverOrigin from config

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue might be due to the URL is not correct.

It's possible, pointing the SDK to wso2 identity server using the latest SDK version. In that case, the `serverOrigin`(Now it has been renamed to `baseUrl`) would be `https://localhost:9443` most probably. No need to mention the app name there.

However, if you're trying to add authentication via [Asgardeo](https://console.asgardeo.io/), the format would be more likely `https://api.asgardeo.io/t/<tenant>`.